# How do I select environment variables using os.environ (using VSCode & Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am building an Azure Function in VSCode and am unable to get my function locally to refer to the environment variables that I am adding to local.settings.json as I get an error when trying to access my environment variable. I want to access the one named clientId.

**My local.settings.json:**

```json
    {
      "IsEncrypted": false,
      "Values": {
      "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
      "clientId": "test123"
      }
    }
```

**My script:**

```py
import os
import azure.functions as func

print(os.environ['clientId'])
```

**The error:**

```
  File "c:\Users\xxxx\source\Repos\xxxx\Python\xxxx\HttpTrigger1\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(os.environ['clientID'])
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py", 
line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'clientID'
```

To try and troubleshoot this I tried to print all environment variables expecting to see my local.settings.json however I do not see anything resembling the local.settings.json file.

**Script:**

```py
import os
import azure.functions as func

print(os.environ)
```

**Response:**

```
environ({
   "ALLUSERSPROFILE":"C:\\ProgramData",
   "APPDATA":"C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Roaming",
   "CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME":"\\\\.\\pipe\\crashpad_4888_HMCJUBDIIALYYBRP",
   "COMMONPROGRAMFILES":"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files",
   "COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files",
   "COMMONPROGRAMW6432":"C:\\Program Files\\Common Files",
   "COMPUTERNAME":"xxxx",
   "COMSPEC":"C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
   "DEPLOYMENT.EXPIRATION.CHECK.ENABLED":"false",
   "DRIVERDATA":"C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData",
   "FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING":"Internet Explorer",
   "FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING":"Default",
   "HOMEDRIVE":"C:",
   "HOMEPATH":"\\Users\\xxxN",
   "LOCALAPPDATA":"C:\\Users\\xxxN\\AppData\\Local",
   "LOG4J_FORMAT_MSG_NO_LOOKUPS":"true",
   "LOGONSERVER":"\\\\xxxxxxxxxx",
   "NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS":"8",
   "ONEDRIVE":"C:\\Users\\xxxN\\OneDrive - xxx",
   "ONEDRIVECOMMERCIAL":"C:\\Users\\xxxN\\OneDrive - xxx",
   "ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP":"undefined",
   "OS":"Windows_NT",
   "PATH":"C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Foundation\\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\windows\\system32;C:\\windows;C:\\windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files\\Gemalto\\Classic Client\\BIN;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Gemalto\\Classic Client\\BIN;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\170\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Azure Data Studio\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\dotnet\\;C:\\Users\\xxxN\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;;C:\\Users\\xxxxN\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Azure Data Studio\\bin;C:\\Users\\xxxxN\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin",
   "PATHEXT":".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL",
   "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE":"AMD64",
   "PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER":"Intel64 Family 6 Model 140 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel",
   "PROCESSOR_LEVEL":"6",
   "PROCESSOR_REVISION":"8c01",
   "PROGRAMDATA":"C:\\ProgramData",
   "PROGRAMFILES":"C:\\Program Files",
   "PROGRAMFILES(X86)":"C:\\Program Files (x86)",
   "PROGRAMW6432":"C:\\Program Files",
   "PSMODULEPATH":"C:\\Users\\xxxxN\\Documents\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules",
   "PUBLIC":"C:\\Users\\Public",
   "SESSIONNAME":"Console",
   "SYSTEMDRIVE":"C:",
   "SYSTEMROOT":"C:\\windows",
   "TEMP":"C:\\Users\\xxxxN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp",
   "TMP":"C:\\Users\\xxxxN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp",
   "UID":"fxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxf",
   "USERDNSDOMAIN":"BLUE.LOCAL",
   "USERDOMAIN":"BLUE",
   "USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE":"BLUE",
   "USERNAME":"xxxxx",
   "USERPROFILE":"C:\\Users\\xxxxN",
   "WINDIR":"C:\\windows",
   "ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN":"1",
   "TERM_PROGRAM":"vscode",
   "TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION":"1.66.0",
   "LANG":"en_US.UTF-8",
   "COLORTERM":"truecolor",
   "VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE":"\\\\.\\pipe\\vscode-git-33ca814331-sock",
   "VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE":"C:\\Users\\xxxN\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe",
   "VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"--ms-enable-electron-run-as-node",
   "VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN":"c:\\Users\\xxxxN\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\resources\\app\\extensions\\git\\dist\\askpass-main.js",
   "GIT_ASKPASS":"c:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\resources\\app\\extensions\\git\\dist\\askpass.sh",
   "PYTHONUSERBASE":"C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages"
})
```

Comment: azure copies that file into os.environ presumably ... how are you running your script? if you are just doing `python myscript.py` it wont load that file i dont think ...

Comment: The json file says `clientId`, but the python code says `clientID`.  Those are different.

Comment: Actually it seems in preparing this question and reduced code example I have made a typing error but this typing mismatch does not exist in my full script.

Comment: To run my script I am pressing the "run python file" button in vs code

Comment: Your Python code does nothing to load the `local.settings.json`.  What makes you think that the Python interpreter will read that file and make its contents available to you as environment variables?  There's no reason to expect that behavior from just the 3 line script that you provide.

Answer (score 1):

`local.settings.json` is a configuration file used by Azure Functions. It is not something linked to Python itself that will directly work in any environment.

Using this module, if you start the Azure Function with it, it should simulate locally the AzureDevOps context.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions

Comment: Thanks, the link provided is exactly how I created my azure function in vs code hence why I am perplexed I can not seem to run it locally. I assumed local.settings.json were the versions of the variables to run locally which might differ from the environment variables when deployed